# Custom directive for input field with label and validation is not working

Tags: angularjs-directive

I am new to angularJS. I am trying to write a custom directive for input tag. I want a custom input as shown in the below picture.

### [image]

Basically it should render the label name, text field and some validation message if the user enters a invalid value. below is the code which I tried but which is not working as expected.

```
var controller = angular.module('FundooDirectiveTutorial', [])
    .controller('FundooCtrl', function ($scope)
    {
        $scope.validValues = ["ABC", "XYZ"];
        $scope.inputField = "Hello World";
        $scope.updateInput = function (input)
        {
            $scope.inputField = input;
        };
        $scope.isValid = function ()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.validValues.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.validValues[i].toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.inputField.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        };
    });

    controller.directive('fundooInput', function ()
    {
        return {
            restrict:'E',

            scope:{
                labelName:"=",
                inputValue:'=',
                onInputChange:'&',
                isValid : '&'
            },
            template:'<div><label>scope.labelName</label><input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" ng-change="updateValidity(inputValue)">' +
                    '<h6 ng-show="valid">Entered value is not correct</h6></div>',
            link:function (scope, elem, attrs)
            {
                scope.updateValidity = function (newValue)
                {
                    scope.inputValue=newValue;
                    scope.onInputChange(newValue);
                    scope.valid = scope.isValid();
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML file is

```
<html ng-app="FundooDirectiveTutorial">
<head>
    <title>Input Directive Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/FundooCtrl.js"></script>
</head>

    <body ng-controller="FundooCtrl">
        input value is {{inputField}}<br/>
        <fundoo-input labelName="Name" input-value="inputField" on-input-change="updateInput(inputField)" is-valid="isValid()"/>
        Latest input value is {{inputField}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Can some one please help what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can work this using **bootstrap controls**, there are two types of control available in bootstrap which fullfill your basic need of having a alert box on the right.

**1) Using popover
2) Using Tooltip**

So where to write the code in your directive where you have created a template to work on

```
template:'<div><label>scope.labelName</label><input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" ng-change="updateValidity(inputValue)">' +
         '<h6 ng-show="valid">Entered value is not correct</h6></div>',
```

first of all change your element h6 to some other span or div and include the bootstrap controls as the attribute for this like updated code is

```
template:'<div><label>scope.labelName</label><input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" ng-change="updateValidity(inputValue)" >' +
         '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-show="valid" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" title="Entered value is not correct">Entered value is not correct</button></div>',
```

and this is how import the bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css and it's done. Hope this would help.